# How does this works? verts = [[float(i) for i in r[:3]] for r in rows]

Tags: python, csv, splines

I looked over here and found a csv reading script that creates curves, wich is exactly what I need, it´s cool, but I need to modify it because I need to read a differently formated csv, in fact I need to create different lists with different values, my CSV looks like this:

uniquename, x,      y,      z,      diameter,   name
401_JJ,     2800,   15500,  21400,  406,        401_JJ
a,          2800,   15500,  24150,  406,        401_JJ

The thing is that I need to extract a names list, a unique names list, a diameter list and a coordinates list.

I know that with this code I extract the first 3 rows and convert them to a vector collection, but I don´t know how to modify this and extract specific positions, for example, 2,3,4 as vectors, 1 as string, 5 as float and 6 as string.

Hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the excellent [csv module built into Python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) for that. The Python documentation has plenty of examples on how to read and write CSV files.

Once you have a row, you can convert individual bits to other objects, like so:

```
vec = mathutils.Vector([float(coord) for coord in row[1:4]])
```

The explicit conversion to float is necessary as CSV is untyped, so every field is returned as string.

The `[f(x) for x in collection]` construct is called a list comprehension, and is also explained [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: So in this case, using "row[1:3]" is telling Blender that the Vector coord should be created with the data existent in row 1, 2 and 3?
For example, if I want to pick rows 2,3 and 4 I should use "row[2:4]", correct?
Thanks for the docs link, I´m going to check it right away.

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be `[1:4]`: from index 1 up to but not including index 4.